# Kohana Route for API - Subdirectories, ids, formats

Tags: api, directory, routes, format, kohana-3.2

I'm trying to create a route in Kohana 3.2 that would match URIs like

```
api/article/get.json

api/article/get/123.xml

api/blogpost/post.json

api/user/get/username.json
```

So the idea is that I have a sub directory called API where I have all my api controllers, the route matches the controller, the method, a format, and alternatively and id.

I have set the following rout in my `application/bootstrap.php`

```
Route::set('api', 'api/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>).<format>)',
  array(
    'format' => '(xhtml|xml|json|rss|html|php|serialize)',
  ))
  ->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'api',
    'controller' => 'blogposts',
    'action' => 'get',
    'format' => 'json',
  ));
```

I have played with multiple combinations of this route, but every time I get the following error message for a url like: `localhost/api/blogposts/post.json`

```
HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL api/blogposts/post.php was not found on this server.
```

It seems to me that this should be fine, but I must be doing something wrong.

Help is appreciated.

Onema

**EDIT**

My default controller is set to be last, just thought I would mention it as I found this post in SO
[Kohana 3 route not matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711091/kohana-3-route-not-matching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a newb mistake but the problem was not the route, rather the class name here is why:

I placed my controller in

```
application/classes/controller/api/bloposts.php
```

And the name of the class was

```
class Controller_Blogposts extends Controller {
  ...
}
```

After spending some time debugging the application I found that the issue was not the route so much as the name of the class which should have been

```
class Controller_Api_Blogposts extends Controller {
  ...
}
```

As the autoloader will map the route `api/blogposts.json` to the class "**Controller_Api_Blogposts**".

In the Kohana 3.2 [Conventions and Coding Style](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/conventions), they have a nice table that shows what the class name is and what the file path should be:

[image: Class name and corresponding file path in Kohana 3.2]

I'm not sure 100% the technicalities behind route mapping with directories, but If the route maps to a `<directory>` (in this case is **api**) it is safe to assume that **api** is with in the "*application/classes/controller*" directory.